# Data missing when using group-element as opposed to dots

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, d3.js

I use this code:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return domainOnlyScale(parseFloat(d.Size)+0.01); } )
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.x+(Math.random() * 0.25) - 0.125); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y+(Math.random() * 0.25) - 0.125); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.color); })
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return strokecolor(d.color); });
```

And everything works. All data points show up. Now I change this part of the code to:

```
console.log(data); // Shows all data points!
var groupings = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d){return "translate("+(x(d.x+(Math.random() * 0.25) - 0.125))+","+y(d.y+(Math.random() * 0.25) - 0.125)+")"}); //used console.log here)

groupings.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return domainOnlyScale(parseFloat(d.size)+0.01); } )
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.color); })
    .style("stroke-width", "1px")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return strokecolor(d.color); });

groupings.append("text")
        .attr("class", "bubbletext")
        .attr("dx", function(d){ return -4 })
        .attr("dy", function(d){ return +5 })
        .text( function(d) { return d.category.substring(0,1); } );
```

I used another console.log inside the function of the transform of the groupings-creation, and the data is already filtered there. From a few tries it seems as if the first ~15 entries are missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably have other `g` elements on the page already. Add a class to the `g` elements you're using for this, e.g. `svg.selectAll("g.dot").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("class", "dot")`.

Comment: Made sense and worked - thanks a lot Lars. Can you enter this as the solution so I can select it as such? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have `g` elements on the page already. These are getting selected through `svg.selectAll("g")` and then matched to data. Hence, the enter selection doesn't contain all the elements you expect to be there.

The fix is simple -- assign a class to those `g` elements you're using here to be able to distinguish them from the rest and select accordingly:

```
svg.selectAll("g.dot")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("g")
   .attr("class", "dot");
```